# Error in production only - "The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Int32' Parameter name: value"

Tags: entity-framework, enums, projection, production

I'm receiving the following error:

```
The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Int32'
Parameter name: value
```

whilst using the entity framework. I believe this to be a projection problem with enums as previously mentioned in the following question:

[Entity framework mapping enum : The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Int32' Parameter name: value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990196/entity-framework-mapping-enum-the-specified-value-is-not-an-instance-of-type)

What I'm confused about is, my code works perfectly on my local PC, but as soon as the code is published onto the production server, the server throws those errors. I'm making sure that my reference to the entity framework is being copied to the server (EF 4.4) and nothing else is being cached etc.

Is there anything I need to check on the production server to get this working?

Comment: Are you running .NET Framework 4.5 on your local box while .NET Framework 4 on the production server?

Comment: Hi, yep it looks like the server is on 4, and my pc has 4.5 installed. I'm assuming this is the reason, garrr. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the difference can be between 32/64 bit machines. Try specifying your enum type

```
public enum MyEnum : int  {... }
```

Anyway this is similar to

[Entity framework mapping enum : The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Int32' Parameter name: value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990196/entity-framework-mapping-enum-the-specified-value-is-not-an-instance-of-type)